# Printing inside pubnub callback function not displaying

Tags: python, printing, git-bash, pubnub

I am testing the pubnub API in Python and have trouble printing messages inside the subscription callback function, which triggers when a new message appears.

In the code below, received messages are somehow queued and printed only
when some message is sent after. Everything executes without delay,
only the actual printing is delayed.

```py
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from pubnub.enums import PNStatusCategory
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
import pubnub

import os
import logging

CHANNEL = 'channel1'
USER = 'user'

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.publish_key = ""
pnconfig.subscribe_key = ""
pnconfig.uuid = "serverUUID-PUB"

pnb = PubNub(pnconfig)

class ReceiverCallback(SubscribeCallback):

    def message(self, pnb, event):
        if event.message['text'] == 'exit':
            os._exit(0)
        print(logging.info(event.message['text'])) # this doesn't show

pnb.add_listener(ReceiverCallback())
pnb.subscribe().channels(CHANNEL).execute()

while True:
    txt = input('')
    pnb.publish().channel(CHANNEL).message({
        'from': USER,
        'text': txt
    }).sync()
    print(txt) # this shows
```

If I replace `print` with `logging.warn` and set `pubnub.set_stream_logger('pubnub', logging.INFO,30)` before the loop, then messages show as `ERROR:root:<message>`,
but the same doesn't work with `logging.info` and `logging.debug` shows additional
logging by the API's implementation.

I don't think the tutorials, from which I got the code (basically the same) do not mention this.
I've also failed to find this issue being mentioned anywhere else.

EDIT: This turns out only to be a problem when running the script from git bash, but not from e.g. idle or Powershell.

Comment: isn't `os._exit(0)` preventing the `print` from happening? I will test myself but just throwing that out there for you to test. Also, I redacted your PN keys. Never expose your keys to the public.

Comment: Also, it appears you are folowing the [PN Python Quickstart](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/quickstarts/python). It explicitly instructs you to put publisher code in one script and subscriber in another because the subscribe call is blocking.

Comment: @CraigConover Thanks, somehow hiding the keys slipped my mind. I think `os._exit(0)` runs only if the received message is "exit", so that shouldn't be a problem.  About blocking, my theory is that output is disabled for some types of loggers. E.g. I can replace print with `file.write(...)` and the writing is synchronized with the program. Basically anything that runs instead of `print` executes, the only issue seems to be the actual displaying of print.

Comment: @CraigConover I've realized the problem seems to be running the python script with git bash. When running from idle everything seems to work fine. I'll update the question.

Comment: So does that resolve the issue or does the nature of the question just change to "why no work with git bash"?

Comment: @CraigConover Yes, from my side the issue is largely resolved. I do realize the nature of the question changed entirely, but it may be relevant to someone in the future.

Comment: Understood. I just wanted to make sure the PubNub portion was resolved. The rest is out of my wheelhouse :) Cheers!